# subprocess calling program that reads files in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program prog1 that takes as input variables the rootname of the output and input files. So on the command line I would call

```
prog1 -o output input
```

to process input.in and input.log and output the result to output.1, output.2, ...

Now, I need to call this program from a python routine.

```
subprocess.call(["prog1", '-o output input'])
```

gives me the following error though:

> Couldn't find a .log or .out file

which I would normally get if the input.log file is missing.

I guess I am doing something very stupid and I know I have not quite understood what subpocess actually does internally, therefore any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're trying to run manually `prog1 -o output input` from the same directory- does it work ?

Comment: Maybe input or output files are in a different directory

Comment: @ alfasin: Yes that was the first thing I tried; @user3926962: Then the first test would not have worked... Thank you anyway for your answers. The correct solution is by now given below by Rob Davis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code for prog1, I don't know eactly how many arguments it takes, but currently you are only passing in two through your subprocess.call().

You probably need to split up the args in your call.  Perhaps one of the folowing:

```
subprocess.call(['prog1', '-o', 'output', 'input'])
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['prog1', '-o output', 'input'])
```

Based on your notes above, I think the second one is what you want.  But I would need to see how prog1 handled arguments to be sure.

Comment: Hi Rob! The first version worked. Could you explain what happens why? In which cases is the first version correct, in which is it the second?

Comment: So basically, the spec for subprocess.call is 'subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)' - so it takes a series of standard arguments, followed by some keyword arguments. The first argument must be the subprocess you wish to launch. The arguments following it must be the arguments for the subprocess. What you originally submitted was akin to the following command argument $>prog1 "-o output input". It was a call to launch prog1 with the argument "-o output input", but what you wanted was $>prog1 -o output input.

Comment: Honestly, I can't give you a good example of when you would want the second over the first.  Generally, you want the first (just remember that if it is a keyword argument, like `password=abc123` you would want that to be submitted as `subprocess.call(['prog', 'password=abc123'])` rather than `subprocess.call(['prog', 'password', 'abc123']) because it is a keyword argument that must be submitted as a key/value pair.  I thought maybe, in your case, you wanted the second because the error massage was saying it couldn't find the third argument rather than saying it was missing a second.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!